# Solving a system of nonlinear PDEs with a piecewise initial condition

Tags: plotting, differential-equations, numerical-integration, nonlinear

I need somw help in using NDsolve. I have a complex system of two PDEs which I am trying to solve numerically (shown in the code below with initial conditions and boundary value condition). I want to specify the initial condition as a piecewise function but NDSolve does not seem to like it. I have included samples of my code and the error messages(including stack trace). I am also having problems with graphing the solution. **Note** I have been testing the problem using random values for constants, but for the purposes of testing problems I have chosen realistic fixed values for the constants.

In summary my problem is

- Running NDsolve without errors.
- Graphing the solution.

If you need any clarifications just ask.

**New Edit**

Part of the original problem has been solved. But a new problem has appeared, the problem is now very stiff. The code and error message has been updated with the changes suggested.

```
ClearAll["Global`*"]
Needs["DifferentialEquations`NDSolveProblems`"];
Needs["DifferentialEquations`NDSolveUtilities`"];
(*Constants*)
(*{p1,p2,c1,c2 ,T10, T20,a1, a2,b1, b2,D1, D2,K1, \
K2,N1initial,N2initial}=RandomReal[{0,50},{16}]*)
{p1, p2, c1, c2 , T10, T20, a1, a2, b1, b2, D1, D2, K1, K2, N1initial,
   N2initial} = {9.8`, 15`, 1`, 2`, 45`, 46`, 6`, 10`, 5`, 2`, 3`, 4`,
   100`, 100`, 36`, 25`}
N1i[x_] := 
  Piecewise[{{0, x < 1/10}, {0, x > 3/10}, {N1initial, 
     1/10 <= x <= 3/10}}];
N2i[x_] := 
  Piecewise[{{0, x < 7/10}, {0, x > 9/10}, {N2initial, 
     7/10 <= x <= 9/10}}];
tmax = 10;

(*System Equations*)
(*Predefined functions*)
T1[t_] := (p1 T10)/(c1 - p1) (E^(-p1 t) - E^(-c1 t));
T2[t_] := (p2 T20)/(c2 - p2) (E^(-p2 t) - E^(-c2 t));
(*PDEs*)
pdeN1 =  D[N1[x, t], t] == 
   a1 N1[x, t] (1 - N1[x, t]/K1) - b1 N1[x, t] T2[t] + 
    D1 D[N1[x, t] D[N1[x, t] + N2[x, t], x], x];
pdeN2 =  D[N2[x, t], t] == 
   a2 N2[x, t] (1 - N2[x, t]/K2) - b2 N2[x, t] T1[t] + 
    D2 D[N2[x, t] D[N1[x, t] + N2[x, t], x], x];
(*initial and boundary value conditions*)
bc = {Derivative[1, 0][N1][0, t] == 0, 
   Derivative[1, 0][N1][1, t] == 0, Derivative[1, 0][N2][0, t] == 0, 
   Derivative[1, 0][N2][1, t] == 0}; 
ic = {N1[x, 0] == N1i[x], N2[x, 0] == N2i[x]};

(*initial and boundary value conditions*)
sol = NDSolve[{pdeN1, pdeN2, bc, ic}, {N1[x, t], N2[x, t]}, {x, 0, 
   1}, {t, 0, tmax}, Method -> "StiffnessSwitching"]
```

[image]

**2nd Edit**
The original model is [here](http://journals2.scholarsportal.info/details?uri=/03036812/v23i0001/1_oiptdtacpos) The model description is below
[image]

Here is my attempt to simulate the original model.

```
ClearAll["Global`*"]
Needs["DifferentialEquations`NDSolveProblems`"];
Needs["DifferentialEquations`NDSolveUtilities`"];
(*Constants*)
(*{p1,p2,c1,c2 ,T10, T20,a1, a2,b1, b2,D1, D2,K1, \
K2,N1initial,N2initial}=RandomReal[{0,50},{16}]*)
{p1, p2, c1, c2 , T10, T20, a1, a2, b1, b2, D1, D2, K1, K2, N1initial,
   N2initial} = {9.8`, 15`, 1`, 2`, 45`, 46`, 6`, 10`, 5`, 2`, 3`, 4`,
   100`, 100`, 36`, 25`}
N1i[x_] := 
  Piecewise[{{0, x < 1/10}, {0, x > 3/10}, {N1initial, 
     1/10 <= x <= 3/10}}];
N2i[x_] := 
  Piecewise[{{0, x < 7/10}, {0, x > 9/10}, {N2initial, 
     7/10 <= x <= 9/10}}];
tmax = 10;

(*System Equations*)
(*Predefined functions*)
(*PDEs*)
pdeN1 =  D[N1[x, t], t] == D1 D[N1[x, t] D[N1[x, t] + N2[x, t], x], x];
pdeN2 =  D[N2[x, t], t] == D2 D[N2[x, t] D[N1[x, t] + N2[x, t], x], x];
(*initial and boundary value conditions*)
bc = {Derivative[1, 0][N1][0, t] == 0, 
   Derivative[1, 0][N1][1, t] == 0, Derivative[1, 0][N2][0, t] == 0, 
   Derivative[1, 0][N2][1, t] == 0}; 
ic = {N1[x, 0] == N1i[x], N2[x, 0] == N2i[x]};

(*initial and boundary value conditions*)
sol = NDSolve[{pdeN1, pdeN2, bc, ic}, {N1[x, t], N2[x, t]}, {x, 0, 
   1}, {t, 0, tmax}, Method -> "StiffnessSwitching"]
```

[image]

Comment: 1. `=` in `ic` should be `==`. 2. `e` in `T1`, `T2` should be `E`. 3. `bc` is apparently wrong, there're 4 b.c. for `N1`, two of which are duplicates!

Comment: @xzczd Your advice is very helpful. Now Mathematica tells me my problem is very stiff and stops at a very early time. Do you have any advice to deal with stiffness?

Comment: Are you sure the equation is correct now? Can you add some background information of the equation?

Comment: @xzczd As far as I know no one has tried solving the above equation and analytical solutions are difficult to find (I derived part of the model from physical data and previous work from many authours). I have added notes on the original model and the original paper. If you can help me solve numerically the original model I will consider the problem to be solved.